# Android Studio Shared Perefences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I don't understand how to retrieve shared preferences if i create them in the onCreate.  For example if i enter the application for the 2nd time and i want to use the data in the sharedprefs if i create them in the onCreate will it not just reset when i enter the app again?

I have the PREF name:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "DrinkingPrefsFile";
```

then in the OnCreate i have the 'constructor' of the shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("name", "Elena");
editor.putInt("cola", 0);
editor.commit();
```

But i want to be able to use this info in other activities even after i open this acitvity more than once so the info can be updated and changed according to the data in the activity using the shared prefs.

Comment: Retrieve the `SharedPreference` in `onRsume()` to ensure you get the latest value each time the user enters the screen

Comment: Read some basics about SharedPreferences. No, they will not be reset.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because... some study is required before you start using something. And, in this case it's something you can easily dig in the [Google](https://www.google.com) goldmine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you write those values you may read them everywhere in your code like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("general_settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String name = prefs.getString("name", null);
```

Where "this" is instance of a context

They are saved as long as the user does not clear the app's data and you do not delete it.